# Why does searching for YouTube videos using the Python API in Google App Engine go slowly and give me this warning?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

My application is a modification of the "Getting Started Guide" for the YouTube Data Python API [found here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#GettingStarted). Here is my code:

```
def initialize():

    yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()

    # Turn on HTTPS/SSL access.
    # Note: SSL is not available at this time for uploads.
    yt_service.ssl = True

    yt_service.developer_key = 'ACTUAL_API_KEY'
    yt_service.client_id = 'CLIENT_ID'

def getTopVideo(self, searchTerm):
    yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
    query = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeVideoQuery()
    query.vq = searchTerm
    query.orderby = 'relevance'
    query.racy = 'include'
    feed = yt_service.YouTubeQuery(query)
    return feed.entry[0]
```

Whenever the "getTopVideo" code executes inside of my Google App Engine application, I get a warning:

```
WARNING  {timestamp} urlfetch_stub.py:423] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host']
```

Another issue is that when I try to make several requests (~5), there is anywhere between a 0.5 and 1 second delay between searches. I can tell this by looking at the timestamps of the warning shown above.

What can I do to get rid of this warning and allow searches to be made more quickly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't you be using the `yt_service` you create in `initialize()`

Comment: Yes, you are right. The issue still persists after fixing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a security "feature" in app engine:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Request_Headers

Here's the actual code that does the stripping on line 238:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/urlfetch_stub.py?r=56

The person here that encountered this error worked around it by using try/except, which may not be the best solution, but it seems that app engine will not let through otherwise:
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/91

Comment: It looks like it's something you can't work around if you're using Google App Engine. Sort of counter intuitive since all I'm using are Google APIs

Comment: Yeah, agree - it's extremely counter intuitive! Although you can just catch the error and move past it, so that your webapp doesn't crash out.

Comment: I'm not experiencing an error like the Tweepy user was, which is also strange. I just get a warning and it slows up the application. Thanks for the response

Comment: That's very interesting. I'm going to look into this a bit more and see if I can replicate the error. Maybe the GAE team made some changes to streamline this a bit.